# Putting Horizontal Box inside a Vertical Box in Gtk+3

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, gtk, gtk3

I have made following GUI using GTK+3 in python:

```
    Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="File Manager")
    self.set_size_request(800, 600)
    self.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)

    vertical_box = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)
    self.add(vertical_box)

    menu_bar = create_menu_bar()
    vertical_box.pack_start(menu_bar, False, False, 0)

    tool_bar = create_tool_bar()
    vertical_box.pack_start(tool_bar, False, False, 0)

    horizontal_box = Gtk.Box()
    vertical_box.pack_start(horizontal_box, False, True, 0)

    side_bar = create_side_bar()
    horizontal_box.pack_start(side_bar, False, False, 0)
    horizontal_box.set_halign(1.0)

    list_view = create_list_view()
    horizontal_box.pack_start(list_view, True, True, 0)
```

It is basically a file manager. The problem is the items in list_view is taking whatever minimum space it requires. AS you can see in the following images:

[image: When list takes the space of the whole screen, but still there is a white border near size column]

[image: When there are fewer items in the list even the sidebar size is reduced]

In the first image, the list takes the space of the whole screen, but still, there is a white border near size column.

In the second image, there are fewer items in the list even the sidebar size is reduced.

Sidebar is taking the size of list_view, how to avoid this?

How can I properly format my gui, and how can I give proper padding and spacing to columns of list_view?

Comment: [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please. This code snippet can't be run.

Comment: Here is the github link - https://github.com/hell-abhi/File-Manager. You need to run just the layout.py file in it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should set hexpand and vexpand directly to `list_view`:

```
list_view.set_hexpand (True)
list_view.set_vexpand (True)
```

Second: set_halign and set_valign require not a number, but enum value:

```
horizontal_box.set_halign(Gtk.Align.FILL)
```

---

Concerning column width: [GtkTreeViewColumn](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTreeViewColumn.html) has a bunch of methods to control sizing:

```
set_sizing
set_resizable
set_fixed_width
set_min_width
set_max_width
```

Comment: I did set_halign(Gtk.Align.START). My side_bar is aligned correctly now. I am adding the list_view inside a ScrolledWindow and the output is quite small horizontally. How should I fix that?

Comment: "Small" is not something measurable. If you haven't changed scroll policy, should follow size request (800 by 600).

Comment: For now I solved it using treeviewcolumn.set_expand(True) and scrolled_window.set_min_content_width(1000)

Comment: Means it was so small that nothing was visible and there was a horizontal scrollbar present. I also tried         scrolled_window.set_policy(hscrollbar_policy=Gtk.PolicyType.NEVER, vscrollbar_policy=Gtk.PolicyType.AUTOMATIC), but after this it is just using the minimum required space, creating that white border near 'size' column as shown in the image above.